# How to install a python package with all the dependencies into a Docker image?

Tags: python, docker, pyspark, jupyter, folium

I'm working in **Ubuntu 15.10** with the Docker container for Pyspark **jupyter/pyspark-notebook**. I need to install folium with all it's dependencies and run a Pyspark script into the container. I successfully installed Docker, pulled the image  and run it with the command

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -p 4040:4040 -v /home/$MYUSER/$MYPROJECT:/home/jovyan/work jupyter/pyspark-notebook
```

Then, I execute the code example without any issues

```
import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext('local[*]')

# do something to prove it works
rdd = sc.parallelize(range(1000))
rdd.takeSample(False, 5)
```

I looked for the conda environment in `/opt/conda` (as it says in the [documentation](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/pyspark-notebook)) but there is no conda in my `/opt` folder. Then, I installed miniconda3 and folium with all the dependencies as a normal Python package (no Docker involved).

It doesn't work. When I run the image and try to import the package with `import folium` it doesn't find the folium package:

```
ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-af6e4f19ef00> in <module>()
----> 1 import folium

ImportError: No module named 'folium'
```

So the problem can be reduced to two questions:

1. Where is the container's *conda*?
2. How can I install the Python package I need into the container?

Comment: To install python pacakges into Docker container, you can either create a new Dockerfile `FROM jupyter/pyspark-notebook` and add `conda install --quiet --yes 'folium'`, or just login to the container `sudo docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash` and install directly inside the container (first method preferred)

Comment: A Docker container is isolated, it doesn't see anything installed on your machine. You need a Dockerfile where you'll state the command to install folium, just  like warmoverflow commented. Don't use the second method, a container reverts to its initial state when restarted, you lose any change made directly inside a running container.

Comment: Thanks [warmoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4190526/warmoverflow) and [ShanShan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5388620/shanshan) for your comments!. I didn't understand that the container has its own file system. I did `$ docker my_containers_name ls /opt/conda` and found the conda enviroment

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To answer the first question *Where is the conda environment?* we just need to execute in console `$ docker my_containers_name ls /opt/conda`.

Second question has two options:

- We can open the containers console by executing the command

  `$ docker exec -it my_containers_name /bin/bash`

  and install the package like a normal conda package

  `conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge folium`
- We can modify the Dockerfile of the Docker image or create a new one extending the previous one. To create a new Dockerfile and add the lines

  ```
  FROM jupyter/minimal-notebook
  USER jovyan
  RUN conda install --quiet --yes --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge folium && conda clean -tipsy
  ```

  And build our new image. If we want to modify the original Dockerfile we must skip the first line.

I create my own [Dockerfile](https://github.com/jocerfranquiz/docker-stacks/blob/master/python3.5-spark1.6.1-nb/Dockerfile) by forking the [original project](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks).

Thanks [warmoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4190526/warmoverflow) and [ShanShan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5388620/shanshan) for your comments